# É obrigatório relacionar as tabelas em banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, mysql

Tenho um leve conhecimento sobre banco de dados e sei usar `JOIN`pra determinados `SELECT`s. Estou montando um DB simples a onde tenho **certeza** absoluta que uma tabela não tem relações com outras. É obrigatório? Há algo relacionado em boas práticas sobre isso?

Comment: Não, não é obrigatório uma tabela estar relacionada a outra, contudo os relacionamentos em um modelo de dados é que são a parte mais importante deste modelo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, pelo contrário. Só faça relações onde precisa. Qualquer coisa só faça se puder justificar adequadamente. Na verdade a forma mais usada de relações é por `JOIN` e nada é necessário previamente para ele funcionar. Só certifique que tem todos os índices necessários para obter a melhor performance.

Esta seria a boa prática, ainda que o melhor é entender o funcionamento de um banco de dados para poder saber o que fazer em todas situações.

Comment: Usar um banco de dados que dá suporte a relacionamento, e não usá-los, comparado a um banco não relacional é desvantagem ?

Comment: Depende, Se não precisa com certeza não. Se precisa pode ser ou não. Eu nunca uso e conheço outros programadores bem melhores do que eu que nunca usam. Não é uma fórmula mágica.